# Flexbox with translate3d

Tags: css, flexbox

If someone used a flexbox with 2 items that take up as much space available both will take equal parts of the container. I'm working with a sliding component(Ionic2) that translates one of the boxes(say the left one) over the other(right one) and I'd like to shrink the other based on the final position of the translated box(so that possible inner flex items can resize accordingly). Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJJyzj) .

```
<h1>Both parts take up the same space.</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">
  </div>
  <div class="item2">
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<h1>They still take up the same space, but the red overlaps the blue.</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item3">
  </div>
  <div class="item4">
  </div>
</div>
```

And the corresponding css

```
.container{
  width:1000px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:gray;
  display:flex;
}
.item1{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-color:red;
}

.item2{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-color:blue;
}

.item3{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-color:red;
  transform:translate3d(100px,0,0);
}

.item4{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

Is it possible without having to transform the second box?

Comment: With transform it is not possible. Why not using `margin` or `padding` instead of transform?

Comment: The transform is used by the framework I'm using. It's dynamically set by JS so changing it is not an option for me.

Comment: Then your friend will be javascript. Cause the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#module-interactions) say: `This module defines a set of CSS properties that affect the visual rendering of elements to which those properties are applied; these effects are applied after elements have been sized and positioned according to the Visual formatting model from [CSS21].`.